# Is it possible to have two valid, competing models with the exact same AIC (or AICc) result?

Tags: model-selection, aic

Say I am modeling occupancy and these are two of several models in my candidate set: 
Ψ(covariate A + covariate B + covariate C)p(.) 
Ψ(covariate A + covariate D + covariate B)p(.)

Is it possible for these two models to be valid (no errors) have the exact same results (a "tie") for AIC?

Comment: If your models are making discrete predictions, then it is certainly possible, either because they make the same predictions or because the errors in their different predictions offset each other.  If your models are making continuous predictions, the more likely cause of equality is that they are making the same predictions

Comment: Mathematically, it is certainly possible. However, in practice, if they are the same, it is most likely that the two models are equivalent in some way. More specifically, one model is a re-parameterization of another.

Comment: @Henry, Tim: these are good answers, not only comments. Consider posting them.

Comment: @Tim, see my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, it is certainly possible. However, in practice, if they are the same, it is most likely that the two models are equivalent in some way. More specifically, one model is a re-parameterization of another. In your case, for example, if $D=B+C$, that would be a re-parameterization.